# Ant build and Eclipse build different result

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am quite new with ANT build. Currently I am building an ANT task to build JAR file but the result after compile it quite different with JAR built with Eclipse IDE.

I am using JRE from WAS 9 for both ANT and Eclipse compilation.

Here's an example from Eclipse

```
CachedCountry$1()
{
    this$0 = CachedCountry.this;
    super();
}
```

And this is from ANT

```
CachedCountry$1()
{
    this.this$0 = CachedCountry.this;
    super();
}
```

What caused the different happened?

Comment: Eclipse has its own compiler which may differ in small details from javac.

Comment: Can I check which compiler eclipse use? And it is possible for javac to use the same compile like eclipse?

Comment: @fahmishah Eclipse uses always its own compiler. In Ant `javac` is used by default, but you can also use the Eclipse compiler.

Comment: The Eclipse compiler is called 'ecj' and can't be changed. See the Eclipse help [here](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-ant_javac_adapter.htm) on how to use it in Ant.